# How to mock DescribeClusterOutput

Tags: go, mocking, amazon-emr, aws-sdk-go

I have written a code that will interact with EMR service and based on a clusterId it will return the cluster status.
I am trying to unit test it but I couldn't figure out.

code:

```golang
func (hc *HandlerConfig) Handler(c entities.Cluster) (string, error) {
    clusterID := aws.String(c.ClusterID)

    clusterDetails, err := hc.EMRClient.DescribeCluster(&emr.DescribeClusterInput{ClusterId: clusterID})
    if err != nil {
        return "error", err
    }

    clusterStatus := *clusterDetails.Cluster.Status.State

    return fmt.Sprintf(clusterStatus), nil
}
```

unit testing code:

```golang
func TestHandler(t *testing.T) {
    emrClient := new(emrtestutils.MockEMR)
    hc := HandlerConfig{
        EMRClient: emrClient,
    }

    input := &emr.DescribeClusterInput{ClusterId: aws.String("j-dfdslkj3kl213kj")}

    // I'M STUCK HERE
    output := &emr.DescribeClusterOutput{
        Cluster
    }

    emrClient.On("DescribeCluster", input).Return(*output.Status.State)
    res, err := hc.Handler(entities.Cluster{ClusterID: "j-dfdslkj3kl213kj"})

    assert.NoError(t, err)
    emrClient.AssertExpectations(t)
    assert.Equal(t, res, output)

}
```

I want to provide mock value of DescribeClusterOutput.

link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/emr/#EMR.DescribeCluster

Comment: `DescribeClusterOutput` is a struct. You can't mock structs.

Comment: Is there any error? Besides, are you using the `testify` package?